# Get the duration of fling in Android

Tags: android

The getDuration method in the Scroller class gets the duration of scroll.

Can we use this method to get the duration of fling as well? Or is there any other way to do that?

```
public final int getDuration ()

Returns how long the scroll event will take, in milliseconds.

Returns
The duration of the scroll in milliseconds.
```

Comment: Uhhh I'm not sure about this, but if I remember correctly, you can just subtract the two event start times from each other and you'll have the duration.

Comment: `getDuration()` can be used for both "scroll" and "fling" movements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we use this method to get the duration of fling as well? Or is
>   there any other way to do that?

Since the duration will be calculated at the start of a fling, the duration we get by using that method during a fling is no doubt the fling's duration.

BTW, this duration depend the initial velocity of the fling. Here is the code snippet of the Scroller, and you can see how it is calculated:

```
    /**
     * Returns how long the scroll event will take, in milliseconds.
     * 
     * @return The duration of the scroll in milliseconds.
     */
    public final int getDuration() {
        return mDuration;
    }

   // Code in the fling() method which will be called based on a fling gesture
   mDuration = getSplineFlingDuration(velocity);

    // The essential method.
    private int getSplineFlingDuration(float velocity) {
        final double l = getSplineDeceleration(velocity);
        final double decelMinusOne = DECELERATION_RATE - 1.0;
        return (int) (1000.0 * Math.exp(l / decelMinusOne));
    }
    private double getSplineDeceleration(float velocity) {
        return Math.log(INFLEXION * Math.abs(velocity) / (mFlingFriction * mPhysicalCoeff));
    }
```

**Update:**

> How can the duration be calculated at the start of a fling?

"At the start of a fling" means at the time when the user of the Scroller detect  a fling gesture.Then he should call the following method with proper parameters if he want to use the fling function of a Scroller:

```
  public void fling(int startX, int startY, int velocityX, int velocityY,
            int minX, int maxX, int minY, int maxY)
```

The duration is calculated inside the upper method. It calculate the total velocity with velocityX and velocityY at first and then pass the velocity to getSplineFlingDuration() method to get a fling duration.I'v paste the code of that method initially and I think it's not difficult for you to understand.

Comment: How can the duration be calculated at the start of a fling? It will be appreciated if you can please elaborate.